# Does Mongoengine allow pull from <variable>?

Tags: pymongo, mongoengine

I have a few pull queries that look like this:

```
Site.objects(siteid).update_one(pull__somelist__refid=myid)
```

I would like to reuse this code by making 'somelist' a variable -  something like this:

```
listvar = 'somelist'
Site.objects(siteid).update_one(pull__<listvar>__refid=myid)
```

I have tried various wrappers such as **[listvar]** and **(listvar)** without success.

Is there a way to inject the variable value into the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to abuse the kwarg notation for this

```
myvar = "some_var"
funky_kwarg = {f"pull__{myvar}__refid": myid}
Site.objects(siteid).update_one(**funky_kwarg)
```

Comment: Nice!   Fstring to Dict to kwarg.     This allowed me to replace 12 lines of if, elif code with just two lines

Comment: happy to help :D